# Available votes remaining in the day?

Tags: discussion

I occasionally find myself approaching the 40 daily votes limit and at times would rather not hit the 40 votes due to losing moderating access to a few of the categories. Is there a way to know how many votes I have remaining? I know I get a tally when I have 5 left. However, I may forget at times if I have 2 or 1 left. It certainly isn't a major issue, just curious if this is available in finding out or some work around someone may suggest.

Comment: You might not get exactly what your asking by design but you can use the Data Explorer to help get an idea per tag example: http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is excellent that you are reaching your daily vote limit to encourage and help the posters of those questions and answers that you are applying them to.

However, the display of remaining votes has been asked for at Meta SE as [Display the number of votes a user has left for the day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1967/215590) and not having this has been designated as *by design*.